# ExtJS View loading

Tags: extjs

I am using this for load views in ExtJs window:

```
autoLoad: { url: '@Url.Content("~/Admin/AddEditAssetTypes/")', 
    scripts: true, 
    nocache: true }
```

But it is not loading views.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to load data using a **path** and not a **url**.

A url is a web address (can be relative) where as a path is a physical file path on the server.

Your code snippet should be something like

```
autoLoad: { 
    url: '/Admin/AddEditAssetTypes/filename.html', 
    scripts: true, 
    nocache: true
}
```

Basically, you should be able to navigate to the `url` config option in your browser. If you can't view it then Ext isn't going to be able to display it in a Panel.